# Convert list which has column names and values to data frame with preserving the values

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have data in form of list which looks like ['abc','bcd','cde',1,2,3]. My problem is that 'abc','bcd' and 'cde' are column names and 1,2,3 are values of each column.

How can I convert list to dataframe preserving the column names and there respective values?

This how my data looks like in list:

```
[ sepal_length  sepal_width  petal_length  petal_width  species
0            5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2        0
1            4.9          3.0           1.4          0.2        0
2            4.7          3.2           1.3          0.2        0
3            4.6          3.1           1.5          0.2        0
4            5.0          3.6           1.4          0.2        0
5            5.4          3.9           1.7          0.4        0]
```

So I dont know if inside it still preserves the data structure or not.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Values are only integers?

Comment: yes the values are integers except column names

Comment: The column names are shuffled with integers or not?

Comment: no. The column names are not shuffled with integers

Comment: The list follows the same sequence as in pandas dataframe it should be. for column abc the value is 1. so the next value for column abc should be 4.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
l = ['abc','bcd','cde',1,2,3]
keys = l[:len(l)//2]
values = [[e] for e in l[len(l)//2:]]
pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(keys,values)))
```

Returns

```
    abc     bcd     cde
0    1       2       3
```

If you have more than 1 value per column :

```
l = ['abc','bcd','cde',1,2,3,4,5,6]
n_columns = 3
#or
n_columns = len([e for e in l if isinstance(e,str)])
keys = l[:n_columns]
values = [list() for _ in range(n_columns)]
for i,e in enumerate(l[n_columns:]):
    values[i%n_columns].append(e)
pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(keys,values)))
```

Returns

```
    abc     bcd     cde
0    1       2       3
1    4       5       6
```

Comment: sorry. But for me it shows: 'slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method'. I am not sure what this means.

Comment: Try the other example, the first one only works if you have one value per column @DevanshuKhokhani

Comment: (it meant that len(l)/2 was not an integer)

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

nb_columns = 3
my_list = ['abc','bcd','cde',1,2,3]

# Extract the data from your list and reshape with the proper form (1 row, X columns)
data = np.reshape(my_list[nb_columns:], (1,nb_columns))

# Create a pandas Dataframe with your data and a list of columns name
my_pandas = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=my_list[:nb_columns])
```

EDIT : for multiple lines

```
my_list = ['abc','bcd','cde',1,2,3,4,5,6]

# Try to count the number of rows present in the list
nb_row = int((len(my_list)-nb_columns)/nb_columns)

# Extract the data from your list and reshape with the proper form (N row, X columns)
data = np.reshape(my_list[nb_columns:], (nb_row, nb_columns))
```

If you have any other questions.

Comment: Wrong solution, because all data are converted to strings.

Comment: When i test, i have integer inside the pandas dataframe. Did you try to run the code before saying that ?